# wamp localhost not working (I know there are few posts but mine is quite weird)

Tags: php, apache, localhost

Ok, let me try to shorten things so less to read.
wamp works fine for the past few months, then I started to learn laravel4 and optionally requires vhost and rewrite_module which works pretty well that when I type in larave.intro as URL it works.

Now I'm trying to use wamp again just going to localhost AND page says
[image]

The title of the page does say 404 Not Found.

Read a few threads, some said go apache->service->Test port 80 and see if there are other ports running port 80. It says

`Your port 80 is actually used by : Server: Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) PHP/5.4.16`

which means my apache is the only one running it isn't it...
this already makes me curious and feeling weird, well alright then I go change my port or 8000 in the `httpd.conf` restart my wamp. and uses localhost:8000 alright now wamp works and I test port 80 again it says
Your port 80 is actually not used.
So nothing is running on my port 80 why can't wamp use it?

And, at first I thought it's my vhost so I deleted the vhost and in my host I deleted 127.0.0.1 laravel.intro too and runs my wamp back to port 80...still doesn't work.
I was thinking then fine I will just use port 8000 BUT then my vhost won't work :(

I was using this as my vhost before

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "J:\wamp\www\laravel4-basic\public"
    <Directory "J:\wamp\www\laravel4-basic\public">
        Options FollowSymLinks Indexes MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
   ServerName laravel.intro
</VirtualHost>
```

and in host it's 127.0.0.1 laravel.intro
now since I'm using port 8000 I suppose I should change the vhost too? so I changed to

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>
```

and laravel.intro doesn't work.  laravel.intro works if I'm using port 80 with `virtualhost: *80` and in URL if I type 127.0.0.1:8000 what popped up is laravel.intro instead of the wamp index and if I use localhost:8000 wamp index comes out.
I'm pretty much so confused now.

Side note:php Admin works fine if I'm using port 80 and in URL I just go `localhost/phpmyadmin`

Anyone knows what I'm talking about here? I'm getting confused a bit myself at the end and anyone can get me back to port 80 with everything works?
(if I have to change port then oh wells better than one works and the other one doesn't)

Please give me some suggestions thanks ~!

Comment: It appears that you just need to setup another vhost for localhost where the DocumentRoot and Directory are pointed to the files you are expecting and the ServerName is `localhost`

Comment: Ah that never came in mind....might as well give it a try tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

completely remove the wamp files and just clean the temp files and www folder where you have installed and restart the system and then reinstall WAMP and run

Comment: That's the last step I want to try hehe

Answer (score 0):

The error message means apache is running, so this is a good thing.

By specifying the  local host url  you are requesting a file called index.htm, index.html or index.php (any one of them depending on your configuration), and the error is merely telling you that the file is not there.

Check that one of these files are in the directory : J:\wamp\www\laravel4-basic\public

If you do that and the problem persists, look for the *error_log in the WAMP log directory. The 404 error message means a file is missing. The error log will tell you which file it is looking for that is missing.

Comment: Yup such file exist in public that's why...and there is one in wamp www file too which is the standard index.php created by wamp.

Comment: What should I look for under the error log? I will check that tomorrow after work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Laravel 4.1 installed in a Windows OS System with WAMP Server and I get it working using the following routine:

To avoid the conflict between localhost and your virtualhost project you can config as follow:

In the httpd.conf remove the # from the following line:

```
#Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

to

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Later you need to modify your httpd-vhosts.conf file from c:/wamp/bin/apacheX.X.X/conf/extra folder (i'm using Windows 8 OS). Here you need to add the following VirtualHosts:

```
#Localhost
<VirtualHost localhost:80>
  ServerName localhost
  DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/"
</VirtualHost>

#My VirtualHost
<VirtualHost appdomain.dev:80>
  ServerName appdomain.dev
  DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/app/public"
</VirtualHost>
```

In this virtualhost app is the project folder and appdomain.dev is the host that I specify in the hosts windows file located in c:/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1 appdomain.dev
```

As you can see it needs two VirtualHosts because if you use only the second VirtualHost you overwrite the localhost access, then you need to specify the Localhost access as a new top virtualhost.

I hope it serves you.

Answer (score 0):

This problem happen cause of port 8000 has been reserved so try to change it by the following :

1. In your command line prompt try :
   `php artisan serve --port=8080`
2. Go to your browser with : `localhost:8080`

   by that it works with me.